Getting the closest parent which is a custom element
I have custom element which has an input element that is not a first grade child. I want to get the parent custom element from the input and I tried using input.closest() but it does not work with custom elements tag names
const card = input.closest("game-card");

I need to get the first parent that is a game card so is there a way to do this with custom elements?

Are you simply complaining about this or do you want an answer to a specific question? I see two questions here: "how can I get the custom parent" and "does .closest() work with custom tags".  Looking for clarification :)

Right, I edited the question and yes the question is how can I get the custom parent.

well done :) another question for clarification; is the input element a custom element too? or is it literally a ?

it seems like .closest('game-card') does work. when are you trying to reference this?  custom-elements have a somewhat confusing lifecycle, DOM querying should be done after the element is 'connected' / added to the document.

I get the input element as event.target and event.target.closest("game-card") returns null with the structure being <game-card><input type="date"></game-card>

Closest() does NOT escape shadowRoot


<game-card>
  <first-level>
      <template shadowrootmode="open">
        <input 
           placeholder="click me"
           onclick="console.log(this.closest('game-card'))">
      </template>
  </first-level>
</game-card>



closest( ) does not escape shadowRoots, so you have to recursively walk "up the DOM" to get the nodes you are after.
Explored and documented at SO Question/Answer:
Custom Element getRootNode.closest() function crossing multiple (parent) shadowDOM boundaries

the closest method parameter would be :
use '#game-card', if custom parent element have id='game-card'
or
use '.game-card', if custom parent element have class='game-card'.
your problem will be resolved.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
